# Rename (Alt +Shft + R) type (residing in jar) in eclipse, operation unavailable on current selection?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an eclipse project with a Class named `User` in my project. This `User` type in present inside a jar and is then included in build path of my project.

Now I have an extended Version of my `User` type say `ExtendedUser` which extend `User` type. I want to replace all Occurrence of `User` type with `ExtendedUser`.

However, when I try refactoring it with **Rename (Alt+Shft+R)**, eclipse gives me `Operation not available on current selection`. It seems to work on other types which don't reside in a jar.

How can I achieve the above refactoring ?

I could do the **search (Ctrl+H)** and replace then, but would have to do some manual changes as the import statements would need to be changed too (and import packages are different for User and ExtendedUser).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use your class `User` anymore. Just make your changes in this class instead of extending the class. If you rename the class all occurencies are changes.

Otherwise you can search with Search > File in the whole project for `User` an replace the needed points with `ExtendedUser`.

Comment: I am not entitled to changes `User` as it's imported from a external library, and as I said searching would involve searching import statements too and then do it